# Onclick method in React is effecting every list item in a table, should only affect the one which is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, set, state

I have a tsx file which creates a table of comments.  When the page is rendered, an array of information representing comments is gathered.  A Set containing the indexes of the comments in the array, which is part of the state, determines whether a link under the comment reads 'show more' or 'show less'.  Once that link is clicked, the index of the comment is added to the Set, and the state is updated with the addition of that index to the Set, if the Set contains the index of a comment when the state is updated, it should read 'show less'.  The problem is when I click that link, it changes the link of each list element in the table, not just one.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { LocalizationInfo } from "emt-localization";
import { DateHandler } from "../handlers/date-handler";
import { UserIcon } from "./user-icon";
import { OnDownloadDocument } from "../models/generic-types";
import { getUserString } from "../models/user";
import { ClaimAction, ActionDetails, ReasonActionDetails, CommentDetails, DocumentDetails } from "../models/action";

const stateChangeActions = new Set<string>([
    'Dispute',
    'Rejection',
    'SetUnderReview',
    'Approval',
    'Recall',
    'Submission',
    'RequestPartnerAction'
]);

const fiveMinutes = 5 * 60 * 1000;

const underscoreRegex = /_[^_]*_/g;

const actionTypeClassMap: {[actionType: string]: string} = {
    'Submission': 'success',
    'RequestPartnerAction': 'warn',
    'Rejection': 'warn',
    'Approval': 'success',
    'Recall': 'warn',
    'Dispute': 'warn',
    'SetUnderReview': 'info',
    'CustomerConsentDeclined': 'rejected'
};

const maxShortLength = 100;

interface ActionsProps {
    readonly localization: LocalizationInfo;
    readonly actions: ClaimAction[];
    readonly onDownloadDocument: OnDownloadDocument;
    readonly isInternalFacing: boolean;
    readonly isHistoryPaneDisplay: boolean;
}

class ActionsState {
    readonly expandedComments = new Set<number>();
}

export class Actions extends React.Component<ActionsProps, ActionsState> {
    constructor(props: ActionsProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = new ActionsState();
    }

    render():JSX.Element {
        const loc = this.props.localization;
        const isInternalFacing = this.props.isInternalFacing;
        const toTime = (action:ClaimAction) => new Date(action.timeStamp).getTime();
        const sortBy = (a:ClaimAction, b:ClaimAction) => toTime(b) - toTime(a);
        const actions = this.props.actions.filter(action => {
            if (isDocumentDetails(action.details)) {
                if (action.actionType == 'DocumentSubmission' && action.details.documentType == 'Invoice') {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
        actions.sort(sortBy);

        const grouped = groupActions(actions);

        return (
            <ul className={`claim-actions ${this.props.isHistoryPaneDisplay ? '' : 'user-comment-box'}`}>
                {grouped.map((actions, index) => {
                    let actionClass = '';
                    actions.forEach(action => {
                        actionClass = actionClass || actionTypeClassMap[action.actionType];
                    });

                    const first = actions[0];

                    const icon = actionClass == 'success' ?
                        sequenceIcon('complete') :
                        actionClass == 'warn' ?
                        sequenceIcon('action-required') :
                        actionClass == 'rejected' ?
                        sequenceIcon('rejected') :
                        actionClass == 'info' ?
                        sequenceIcon('editing') :
                        <UserIcon 
                            user={first.user} 
                            isInternalFacing={isInternalFacing}
                        />;

                    const elements = actions.map((action, actionIndex) => this.renderAction(action, actionIndex));

                    return (
                        <li className={actionClass} key={index}>
                            {icon}
                            <div className="win-color-fg-secondary">
                                <span className="claim-action-name win-color-fg-primary">
                                { getUserString(first.user, isInternalFacing) }
                                </span>
                                <span className="text-caption">
                                    {loc.piece("HistoryItemTitle", 0)}
                                    {DateHandler.friendlyDate(first.timeStamp, true)}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            {elements}
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }

    private renderAction(action:ClaimAction, actionIndex:number):JSX.Element|null {
        const strings = this.props.localization.strings;

        if (action.actionType == 'AddComments' || action.actionType == 'AddInternalComments') {
            return this.renderComment((action.details as CommentDetails).comments, actionIndex);
        }

        const document = isDocumentDetails(action.details) ? action.details : null;
        const documentLink = document ?
            (key:number) =>
                <a
                    key={key}
                    onClick={() => this.props.onDownloadDocument(document.documentId, document.name)}>
                    {document.name}
                </a>
        : null;
        const locKey = `History_${action.actionType}`;
        const localizedFlat = strings[locKey] || "";
        const localized = replaceUnderscores(localizedFlat, documentLink);
        const reason = (action.actionType === 'RequestPartnerAction' || action.actionType === 'Rejection') && action.details ? (action.details as ReasonActionDetails).reasonCode : '';
        const reasonString = reason.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + reason.slice(1)

        if (localized) {
            return (
                <div key={actionIndex}>
                    <div className="claim-action">
                        <span className="text-caption">{localized}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="claim-action">
                        { reasonString && <span className="text-caption"><strong>{strings['ReasonLabel']}</strong>{` ${strings[reasonString]}`}</span> }
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

        console.error(`Unknown action type ${action.actionType}`);
        return null;
    }

    private renderComment(comment: string, actionIndex: number): JSX.Element {
        const strings = this.props.localization.strings;
        const canShorten = comment.length > maxShortLength;
        const shouldShorten = canShorten && !this.state.expandedComments.has(actionIndex);

        const shortened = shouldShorten ?
            comment.substring(0, maxShortLength) + "\u2026" :
            comment;

        const paragraphs = shortened
            .split('\n')
            .map(s => s.trim())
            .filter(s => s);

        const elements = paragraphs.map((comment, i) =>
            <div className="claim-comment" key={i}>
                {comment}
            </div>
        );

        const toggle = () => {
            const next = new Set<number>(this.state.expandedComments);
            if (next.has(actionIndex)) {
                next.delete(actionIndex)
            }
            else {
                next.add(actionIndex);
            }
            this.setState({ expandedComments: next });
        }

        const makeLink = (locKey:string) =>
            <a
                onClick={toggle}>{strings[locKey]}</a>;

        const afterLink = canShorten ?
            shouldShorten ?
            makeLink('ShowMore') :
            makeLink('ShowLess') :
            null;
        return (
            <React.Fragment key={actionIndex}>
                {elements}
                {afterLink}
            </React.Fragment>
        );

    }
}

// Function groups actions together under some conditions
function groupActions(actions:ClaimAction[]):ClaimAction[][] {
    const grouped:ClaimAction[][] = [];

    actions.forEach(action => {
        if (grouped.length) {
            const lastGroup = grouped[grouped.length - 1];

            const timeDifference = new Date(lastGroup[0].timeStamp).getTime() - new Date(action.timeStamp).getTime();
            if (stateChangeActions.has(lastGroup[0].actionType) && action.actionType == 'AddComments' && timeDifference < fiveMinutes) {
                lastGroup.push(action);
                return;
            }
        }
        grouped.push([action]);
    });

    return grouped;
}

function isDocumentDetails(details:ActionDetails|null): details is DocumentDetails {
    return !!details && (details.$concreteClass == 'InvoiceActionDetails' || details.$concreteClass == 'DocumentActionDetails');
}

function sequenceIcon(className: string):JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div className="sequence sequence-status claims-icon">
            <div className={`step ${className}`} />
        </div>
    );
}

function replaceUnderscores(str: string, documentLink: ((k:number)=>JSX.Element)|null, startKey: number=0):JSX.Element[] {
    if (!str) {
        return [];
    }

    const match = underscoreRegex.exec(str);
    if (!match) {
        return replaceDocumentLink(str, documentLink, startKey);
    }

    const firstText = str.substring(0, match.index);
    const middleText = match[0].substring(1, match[0].length - 1);
    const lastText = str.substring(match.index + match[0].length);

    const first = replaceUnderscores(firstText, documentLink, startKey);
    const middle = [<strong className={'claims-emphasis'} key={startKey + first.length}>{middleText}</strong>];
    const last = replaceUnderscores(lastText, documentLink, startKey + first.length + 1);
    return first.concat(middle, last);
}

function replaceDocumentLink(str: string, documentLink: ((k:number)=>JSX.Element)|null, startKey: number=0):JSX.Element[] {
    const replaceIndex = str.indexOf('{0}');
    if (replaceIndex >= 0 && documentLink) {
        return [
            <React.Fragment key={startKey}>{str.substring(0, replaceIndex)}</React.Fragment>,
            documentLink(startKey+1),
            <React.Fragment key={startKey + 2}>{str.substring(replaceIndex+3)}</React.Fragment>
        ];
    }
    return [<React.Fragment key={startKey}>{str}</React.Fragment>];
}
```

Comment: The location and state of the link is determined in the renderComment method and the method that changes the text of the link is the toggle method in the renderComment method. The purpose of the renderComment method is to show the comment and whether or not to have it be expanded or collapsed if there is alot of text

Comment: Could you shorten the code sample so it's easy to identify the central problem? It's harder for SO answerers when they have to look through 267 lines of code.